# filter list of tuples by certain axis

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a csv file with 3 columns of x,y,z coordinates, i.e. this format:

[image]

I used the code below, to import it and process its data:

```py
import csv
from operator import itemgetter

csvfile = open(r'C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\Deep-lizard\x_y_z coor.csv')

inFile = csv.reader(csvfile)
# skip header
inFile.__next__()

#Read and sort the vertices coordinates (sort by x and y)
vertices = sorted( [(float(r[0]), float(r[1]), float(r[2])) for r in inFile], key = itemgetter(0,1) )
```

This turns `vertices` into a list of tuples:
[image]

What I want to achieve is filter the list so that, if the third element in the tuple (i.e. the z coordinate) is bigger than 0, then include that entry (the tuple of 3 elements) in the list otherwise if it's 0 then don't include it. What's the best way of doing this?

Comment: You already used a list comprehension to create the list for "sorted". List comprehensions allow an "if"-part for filtering.

Comment: That's Michael. Appreciate the suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put an `if` statement at the end of a comprehension to filter.

```
In [1]: l = list(zip(range(10),range(0,20,2)))
   ...: l
   ...:
Out[1]:
[(0, 0),
 (1, 2),
 (2, 4),
 (3, 6),
 (4, 8),
 (5, 10),
 (6, 12),
 (7, 14),
 (8, 16),
 (9, 18)]

In [2]: [x for x in l if x[1]<13]
Out[2]: [(0, 0), (1, 2), (2, 4), (3, 6), (4, 8), (5, 10), (6, 12)]
```